# Django 1.7 Admin Form Clean(): How to validate required fields first

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-1.7

I'm trying to validate an admin form by overriding the forms clean() method. The problem I'm having is that the clean() method appears to be called before the models field validation. There's no point in cleaning the data if the required data isn't provided, or if the data was entered incorrectly. How do I get django to validate the fields before cleaning the data?

Django 1.7, python 3.4

model.py:

```
class ElectricityBill(models.Model):
    rate = models.ForeignKey(ElectricityRate, blank = False) # This field should be required in the admin form
```

admin.py:

```
class ElectricityBillForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ElectricityBill

    def clean(self):
        #self.validate_fields() - Something like this?
        rate = self.cleaned_data.get("rate") # Returns None if rate is left blank.
```

I'd like to avoid cleaning the data if rate is None.. otherwise I'd have a lot of If statements checking for Nonetypes. This would also be a pain to manage, because if I added more required fields, or took required fields out, I'd have to edit my clean method.

### EDIT:

Workaround:

```
class ElectricityBillForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ElectricityBill

    def clean(self):
        #self.validate_fields() - Something like this?
        rate = self.cleaned_data.get("rate") # Returns None if rate is left blank.
        if rate == None:
            return
        #Continue cleaning
```

This is awful. It appears to work, because it skips the rest of the cleaning and causes the model validation to run. However, it will be a pain to manage later on.

Comment: Have you tried calling `super(ElectricityBillForm, self).clean()` on the first line of your clean method?

Comment: It's not the case that clean is called before individual field validations. Can you show how you are determining that? What is the effect you are seeing? (And how are you triggering validation?)

Comment: You haven't provided any value for Meta.fields. Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: Lain, I've tried that yes. It returns a dictionary of what I believe is cleaned_data, however it does not return any validation errors from what i can tell, it only returns None if a field is left blank

Comment: Daniel, I'm seeing fields that are required being allowed into the clean() method. I would like these values to return errors before it bothers trying to clean them.